# Python - How to replace a character and a digit while keeping the digit the same?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace

I want to replace \n in front of any digit in mystring, while keeping the digit the same as before.
I tried the following.

```py
mystring = "\n this \n 1. is \n 2. some \n 3. text \n"
k = re.sub('\n \d', '\d', mystring)
k
```

I do not want to replace all "\n". Only the ones in front digits. However in my output, the digits are replaced with "\d" and I want to know how to keep them the same.

My output:

```
'\n this \\d. is \\d. some \\d. text \n'
```

expected output

```
'\n this 1. is 2. some 3. text \n'
```

Comment: Do you mean `\n (\d)` and replace with `\1`? https://regex101.com/r/IQ40o4/1

Comment: Can't you just remove all newlines, and then add one to each end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group `\n (\d)` and in the replacement use `r"\1"`

To match 1 or more digits use `\d+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQ40o4/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5oHW62)

For example

```
import re
mystring = "\n this \n 1. is \n 2. some \n 3. text \n"
k = re.sub(r"\n (\d)", r"\1", mystring)
print(k)
```

Output

> this 1. is 2. some 3. text